# projecteuler wrong answer

Tags: python

here is the problem link   [project euler ,problem no. 21](http://projecteuler.net/problem=21)
my code is in python,

```
def d(n):
    A=[]    
    x=0
    y=0
    for i in range(1,n/2+1):
        if n%i==0:
            A.append(i)

    for i in A:
        x+=i
    B=[]
    for i in range(1,x/2+1):
        if x%i==0:
            B.append(i)
    for i in B:
        y+=i
    if y==n:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

sum=0
for j in range(1,10000):
   if d(j)==1:
        sum+=j
print sum
```

my answer is `40284` which it shows wrong ,can anyone give me the reason

Comment: Try it for lower numbers that you can compute by hand on a paper. Does it work properly? If not, debug your code and check the progress against your solution on the paper.

Comment: it gives right result for exmple case given in the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the description carefully:

> If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, **where a ≠ b**, then a and b are an amicable
>   pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.

You fail to check this constraint. Insert `if x == n: return 0` somewhere in your code and the result should be right.